# Methods and properties in subclasses cannot be prompted

Tags: typescript, class, extends, rollupjs

My appeal is to use different low-level implementations in different environments by building, but I want to hide the corresponding details from the upper-level modules.

What I expect is that the outer layer is a normal way of using the class.

The `buildEnv` variable is used when building with rollupJs.

```js
class subA {
  protected fn() {
    console.log('subA');  
  }
}
class subB {
  protected fn() {
    console.log('subB');  
  }
}

const buildEnv = 'A';
function changeSubClass() {
   return buildEnv === 'A' ? subA : subB;
}

const BaseClass = changeSubClass();
class MainClass extends BaseClass {
  constructor() {
    supper();
    this.fn(); // <--- An error is reported here
  }
}

// Hope to use it this way:
const clsIns = new MainClass();
```

One way to do this is to have subA inherit the MainClass, but for external use you need to get an instance by calling the changeSubClass method:

```js
const buildEnv = 'A';
function createSubClass() {
   const Cls = buildEnv === 'A' ? subA() : subB;
   return new Cls();
}

class subA extends MainClass {
  protected fn() {
    console.log('subA');  
  }
}
class subB extends MainClass {
  protected fn() {
    console.log('subB');  
  }
}

class MainClass implements ISubCls {
  constructor() {
    this.fn();
  }
}

interface ISubCls {
  fn: () => void
}
```

This way of using it is not what I would like.

```js
const clsIns = createSubClass();
```

Comment: createSubClass could create the instance directly in the if statement instead of trying to use the classname as a string. Then you won’t need the interface.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not thinking the OOP way clearly. If I understood correclty, you are trying to select a implementation of class to instantiate it according to environment the program is running.

I recommend you to avoid inheritance in favor of composition. Check the code below:

```js
import { makeSendMailUseCase } from "./make-email-service";

async function main() {
    const sendMail = await makeSendMailUseCase();
    const result = await sendMail.execute("me@host.com", "to@host.com", "testing my email", "Hello ");

    if (result) console.log(' email was sent ')
    else throw new Error('failed sending mail')
}

main().catch(console.log.bind(console))
```

In the above code, the app wants to send an email. For this purpose, will instantiate a `SendMailUseCase` class, which will coordinate this task. In order to send an email, it needs to consume an external service. That service will be injected to the useCase, and to make things easy and clear, a factory pattern enters in action to decide what service will be injected for consuming.
So the main program doesn't care what service is being used in the end.

```js
import { createTestAccount } from "nodemailer";
import { SendEmailUseCase } from "./sendmail-usecase";
import { ProductionEmailService } from "./real-email-service";
import { FakeEmailService } from "./fake-email-service";
import { IEmailService } from "./email-service";

export async function makeSendMailUseCase() {
    const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

    let emailService: IEmailService;

    if (isProduction) {
        const testAccount = await createTestAccount();
        emailService = new ProductionEmailService(testAccount)
    } else {
        emailService = new FakeEmailService();
    }

    return new SendEmailUseCase(emailService);
}
```

The makeSendMailUseCase act as a factory to deliver a fresh new instance of a SendMailUseCase, selecting the concrete implementation of the `IEmailService` based on the environment the app is running.

```js
import { EmailFormat, IEmailService } from "./email-service";

export class SendEmailUseCase {
    constructor(private emailProvider: IEmailService) { }

    execute(from: string, to: string, subject: string, content: string): Promise<boolean> {
        const params = {
            from, to, subject, content, format: EmailFormat.Text
        }

        return this.emailProvider.sendEmail(params);
    }
}
```

The `SendEmailUseCase` simply delegates the task of sending email to whatever concrete implementation was provided in the constructor.

```js
export enum EmailFormat {
    Text,
    HTML
}

export type EmailOptions = {
    from: string;
    to: string;
    subject: string;
    content: string;
    format: EmailFormat
}

export interface IEmailService {
    sendEmail(options: EmailOptions): Promise<boolean>;
}
```

Here goes the `FakeEmailService` implementation:

```js
import { EmailOptions, IEmailService } from "./email-service";

export class FakeEmailService implements IEmailService {
    async sendEmail(options: EmailOptions): Promise<boolean> {
        console.log(options)
        return Promise.resolve(true);
    }
}
```

This implementation just satisfies the contract, doing nothing, but it works.

```js
import { TestAccount, Transporter, createTransport } from "nodemailer";
import { EmailFormat, EmailOptions, IEmailService } from "./email-service";

export class ProductionEmailService implements IEmailService {
    private readonly transporter: Transporter

    constructor(account: TestAccount) {
        this.transporter = createTransport({
            host: account.smtp.host,
            port: account.smtp.port,
            secure: account.smtp.secure,
            auth: {
                user: account.user, // generated ethereal user
                pass: account.pass, // generated ethereal password
            },
        });
    }

    async sendEmail(options: EmailOptions): Promise<boolean> {

        const info = await this.transporter.sendMail({
            from: options.from,
            to: options.to,
            subject: options.subject,
            text: options.format === EmailFormat.Text ? options.content : "",
            html: options.format === EmailFormat.HTML ? options.content : "",
        });

        return info;
    }
}
```

The real production emailservice depends of another library, `nodemailer` to finally delivers emails.

That's it!

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer is really what I want to do.
Your example uses the selective use of factory methods inside Class A to call Class C or D.
This is indeed a standard OOP way, but it limits the flexibility of JS.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Import
// prettier-ignore
interface Logger { info: (msg: string) => void }
// prettier-ignore
class ConsoleLogger implements Logger { info(msg: string): void { console.log("[Console]:", msg) } }
// prettier-ignore
class PinoLogger    implements Logger { info(msg: string): void { console.log("[Pino]:"   , msg) } }

// Part 1: Business Entities
interface UserData {
  name: string
}

class AuthService {
  async getUserData(): Promise<UserData> {
    return { name: "Big Lebowski" }
  }
}

class User {
  constructor(private data: UserData) {}
  name = () => this.data.name
}

class PaymentService {
  constructor(private readonly logger: Logger, private readonly user: User) {}
  sendMoney() {
    this.logger.info(`Sending monery to the: ${this.user.name()} `)
    return true
  }
}

// Step 2: Manual DI / composition root
export async function runMyApp() {
  const logger =
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
      ? new PinoLogger()
      : new ConsoleLogger()

  const auth = new AuthService()
  const user = new User(await auth.getUserData())

  const paymentService = new PaymentService(logger, user)
  paymentService.sendMoney()
}

console.log(" ---- My App START \n\n")
runMyApp().then(() => {
  console.log("\n\n ---- My App END")
})
```